# How to set Sqlite relative path in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, sqlite

How to set path of sqlite database as relative in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:/relative path/socomer.db</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the dot to set relative path:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:./path/socomer.db</property>
```